# Windows are incorrectly grouped under applications

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, window-manager, application-switcher

Sometimes my Windows are incorrectly associated to an application group. For example when I use the application switcher (Alt-Tab) I end up wondering where my chrome browser windows are, only to end up finding them being hidden under the wrong application (i.e. under WebStorm).

This also happens on the window switcher, where wrong icons are being shown and application switcher (chrome windows are assigned under WebStorm), and chrome is not even showing up as Application, even though it is clearly running.

Also on the sidebar it thinks chrome is not even running at all.

This issue is intermittent. I have not found any ways to reproduce it reliably. In most cases logging out and then in again fixes.

How do I go about troubleshooting this issue?

[image: Window Switcher]

[image: Application switcher]

Comment: Use Alt-Tab to switch application windows, and Super-Tab to switch applications... or better yet... learn how to use Workspaces to place applications and their windows on different Workspaces, where they can have a whole space for themselves.

Comment: @heynnema I know how to use workspaces and I know to use both the window switcher and the application switcher. My question was not about how to use them, but how to fix the wrong associations.

Comment: @heynnema I have just updated question ot make it clearer that the question is not about to use the application or windows switcher, but rather how to fix the problem of them not associating windows correctly to their application. Would be great to get some feedback from you on why you thought I was asking on how to use these rather than how to fix them and if this ammedment helps with that confusion.

Comment: One of your other apps, like WebStorm, might be causing the problem. First log in fresh, then start Chrome, see if it appears correctly, then quit Chrome, start WS, restart Chrome and see if it's not shown correctly. Depending on your results, keep checking with running your various apps the same way, to see if a different one is causing your problem, if it's not WS.

Comment: @heynnema logging out and in again, does fix it most cases, because the issue is intermittent (added that missing detail to post now). Did not find a way to reproduce it reliably, but did find that it's not always webstorm. Sometimes it happens with slack. There are not many other apps that I use, but I don't recall the associations being wrong with any app other than Chrome, WebStorm and Slack.

Comment: Well, intermittent problems are sometimes difficult to solve. Keep an eye on the apps to see if you can identify if one of them is doing it.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that I cannot single out one app. Different combinations of Chrome, WebStorm and Slack have been affected in the past.

Comment: I suffer from the same problem @d_inevitable. Some context from my situation: whenever an applications opens another one, it will get grouped under the application that opened it. For example: a) if WebStorm will open the Gnome file explorer: it file explorer is grouped under WebStorm or b) if Slack opens a link, it will open Chrome: and Chrome will appear under Slack.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with the PyCharm editor as well....

Comment: Good to know that I'm not the only one facing this issue! But sad to know that no solution has been posted so far :(

Comment: When I open the Nautilus file explorer from PyCharm, the window is shown under the PyCharm group in the dock. Even after I close all such nautilus windows and open a fresh Nautilus window from the dock, it still appears under PyCharm.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with PHPStorm, very annoying. Currently my "Files" and PHPStorm share the same window previews.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is some kind of bug with the Ubuntu OS. A quick workaround that seems to work occasionally:

1. Close all applications that are being grouped together. (This step seems to be sometimes optional)
2. ALT+F2, then type "r" and press enter for a refresh.